# Replace part of a string in a for loop

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, replace

I want to iterate through the list `followers_list` to edit each item.

```
followers_list = []

for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_followers, screen_name='@'+screen_name, wait_on_rate_limit=True, count=200).items(9000): 
    followers_list.append([follower.profile_image_url_https])
    for i in followers_list:
        print(i.replace('normal', '400x400'))
```

Each item in the list is a URL like `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1xxxxxxx/KLJHG-1367_normal.jpg` that I want to change as `https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1xxxxxxx/KLJHG-1367_400x400.jpg`

I'm returned the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Data\Mes documents\twitter\twitter_dl_pictures.py", line 30, in <module>
    url = [i.replace('normal', '400x400') for i in followers_list]
  File "C:\Data\Mes documents\twitter\twitter_dl_pictures.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
    url = [i.replace('normal', '400x400') for i in followers_list]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. The lines included in the traceback don't match the snippet above.

Comment: Try `followers_list.append(follower.profile_image_url_https)` (without the brackets `[]`) instead of `followers_list.append([follower.profile_image_url_https])`.

Comment: I don't think you want to iterate the followers_list after each additional follower. You also don't likely want to add each follower as a list of one item.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: I don't think that's going to help.

Comment: @quamrana Why not? They're appending a list (`[follower...]`) to another list (`followers_list`), and then iterating through `followers_list` and trying to call `.replace()` on each item in `followers_list`, and in this case, each item is a list. Removing the unneeded brackets fixes this problem.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: You are quite correct. It will make the error message go away. So would `i[0].replace('no...`. However, until we sort out which is the actual code there could be other problems.

Comment: @quamrana It's pretty clear to me that the error message comes from the full code, and the code in the question is just a [example] attempt. The OP could have easily put `url = [i.replace('normal', '400x400') for i in followers_list]` (from the error message) in their code instead of `print(i.replace('normal', '400x400'))`. The only difference is that one just prints the attempt at `.replace()`, and the other uses `.replace()` to add items to a list. We don't, however, know _why_ the OP used a list. Maybe they wanted to replace a list item instead part of a string.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin: Ok, the OP seems to like your suggestion, so maybe its job done for now.

Answer (score 2):

Use that instead:

```
for follower in tweepy.Cursor(api.get_followers, screen_name='@'+screen_name, wait_on_rate_limit=True, count=200).items(9000): 
    followers_list.append(follower.profile_image_url_https)
```

**Explanation**:
Instead of adding the string to the list, you are adding a list containing the string.